# Responsive-styling/desktop-styling doesn't work for JQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, window-resize

Responsive-styling/desktop-styling doesn't work in the following 2 scenarios:
1) Re-size browser window
2) When datatable resides inside collapsed accordion and user opens the accordion the styling doesn't work.

I tried the following, but nothing worked for me except dataTable re-initialization (`$('#table').DataTable({parameter list})`), but it takes heavy time for loading the data, if the row count is very high). I tried the following:

1. `var $dataTable = $('#table').dataTable();`
   `$dataTable .css({ width: $dataTable .parent().width() });`
   `$dataTable .fnAdjustColumnSizing();`
2. `$('#table').fnDraw();`
3. `$('#table').resize();`
4. `$('#table').columns.adjust().draw();`

Comment: How about [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29)?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thanks a lot .. It worked ..
Can you please help me out in one more issue. Here is the URL for detailed description:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085404/jquery-datatable-initilization-takes-a-lot-of-time-need-optimization-when-deals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You need to handle event when content is shown and call [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) and [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods in the event handler. This will recalculate the column widths after a change in the display.

```js
$('#table').DataTable()
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();
```

See [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) and [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/Ltga3n4u/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gyrocode.com.. :)

I need few more help.. Kindly help me out. Here are the URLs:

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131580/if-there-is-no-pagination-in-jquery-datatableinside-accordion-and-user-expands

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085404/jquery-datatable-initilization-takes-a-lot-of-time-need-optimization-when-deals?noredirect=1#comment57903275_35085404