# If there is no pagination in JQuery datatable(inside accordion) and user expands the accordion, it takes huge time for seeing the datatable

Tags: performance, pagination, datatables, jquery-ui-accordion

An accordion contains a JQuery datatable which has more than 100 rows. When user expands the accordion it takes a lot of time for making the datatable visible.

Here is the details:
// declaration of dataTable Properties

> var dataTableProperties = {"bPaginate" : true};

//initialztion of dataTable object

> var $table = $('#table').DataTable(dataTableProperties);

//On button click, that **toggles** to "view All pages"/"add pagination", the code is as:

> if(dataTableProperties .bPaginate)
>     dataTableProperties.bPaginate
>   = !dataTableProperties .bPaginate;

Now, on accordion click I am just showing/hiding the accordion-contents. **But it takes huge time, if the rowCount of the table is more than 100 and "bPaginate" property is false.**

Please help me out..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: "_Need code so that user can see the datatable ..._"  ...need code that demonstrates and / or reproduces the problem, so the poor users here on SO get a chance to help you out at all :)

Comment: Hey @davidkonard, it's been edited.. Kindly go through it.. :) :)

Comment: Somebody help, please :)